# What is $\lim_{\leftarrow},\ \prod^{\leftarrow}$

Tags: notation

In the page 258 of chapter 8 of [Diestel](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/diestel/books/graph.theory/preview/Ch8.pdf), I found these two notations involving left arrow:
$$\lim_{\leftarrow},\  \prod^{\leftarrow}$$

What's the meaning of this?

Comment: cf. [projective limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit)

Comment: Also there is a default command for this: $$ \varprojlim$$

Comment: Helpful !  Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [inverse limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit), also known as projective limit.